# Calculate Average Value of Pixels with Value < 0.5 Using scikit-image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, scikit-image, scikits

Using `scikit-image` package in Python 3 and given an RGB image, how can we calculate the average pixel value (normalized values that range from 0 to 1) for pixels whose value is > 0.5?

I think I manage to mask out the pixels that I want the average to be calculated, how then should we proceed?

```
from skimage.io import imread, imshow
from skimage.transform import resize

imgData = data.imread(dataFilepath, as_grey=True)
imgData = resize(imgData, (256,256))

imgMask = imgData < 0.5
imgData[imgMask] = 0
imshow(imgData)    # correctly shows the pixels that we want selected. the unwanted pixels are blacked out (value = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use NumPy's [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) along with the [`mean()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.mean.html) method for multidimensional arrays:

```
imgData = imread(dataFilepath, as_gray=True)
imgMask = imgData > 0.5
imgAvg = imgData[imgMask].mean()
```

In the snippet above `imgAvg` is the average intensity computed over the pixels in which the intensity value is greater than 0.5. If you intended to black out the image pixels whose value is is less than or equal 0.5 and then compute the average over the whole image, you could use the following code:

```
imgAvg = imgData[imgMask].sum()/imgData.size
```